# How to start a new translation project?

Tags: elementary-project

I want to start/help to translate eOS Desktop to espanhol/spanish (ES), I registry myself at l10n.elementary but couldn't create a project myself.

Is this site still used to translate something in the eOS project?

Comment: Welcome to eOS:SE. To the best of my knowledge, you signed up in the right place. I’m not sure how the process works, though 

Comment: Thank you, sad to hear that :(